# Pysnmp Agent Side MIB Implementation for SNMP v3

Tags: windows-10, python-3.7, pysnmp

I have [pysnmp agent side implementation](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/v1arch/asyncore/agent/cmdrsp/agent-side-mib-implementations.html) done in `snmpV2` and is working fine. I have customized as per my requirements. Now, I want to implement the same in `snmpv3` and I check this [link](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/v3arch/twisted/agent/cmdrsp/agent-side-mib-implementations.html) ,but both implementations look totally different. Also, currently I have implemented [this](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/master/examples/v3arch/asyncore/manager/ntfrcv/observe-request-processing-over-ipv4-and-ipv6.py) to receive notifications. So, Can I use both at the same time. I am not sure how this would be done.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your Command Responder implementation is based on SNMPv1/v2c architecture. You can't support SNMPv3 on it. The only solution is to migrate to [SNMPv3 architecture](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/v3arch/asyncore/agent/cmdrsp/agent-side-mib-implementations.html), which will support all three SNMP versions. Since you have Notification Receiver already implemented within SNMPv3 framework, doing that for Command Responder should not be hard.

You can run both Command Responder (any flavor) and Notification Receiver within the same process and the same main loop.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, Let me try this.

Comment: @llya : I did the changes as given in the ref. link that you shared and I tried to run http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/quick-start.html#fetch-snmp-variable
to get SNMP variables, but it is giving the error: ` No Such Object currently exists at this OID` That object is defined in my MIB File, but is not passed in `Notifications`. Any Idea abt this?